# School series about a young lad and girl who had some kind of portal in a box that looked like a house but had two pillars on the front

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember being shown a series at school (about 1996–1998), and I really enjoyed it. However, all I can remember is:

There was a young lad and girl who had some kind of portal in a box, which, if I remember right, looked like a house but had two pillars on the front. Then the doorway became the portal. Towards the end of the series, the portal was massive, and something was threatening to come through it.

I know it’s not much to go on, but it’s really annoying me now.

It was a series, and I think it was shown on BBC (it was definitely shown in England and in English).

I've ruled out *Chocky* (1984).

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: Are you thinking of [Chocky](http://www.moviemuser.co.uk/MovieImages/chocky-slideshow-pic.jpg)?

Comment: U also remember a similar from the same time, being on the air in Canada too, I don't remember much except a portal being the main focus of the show and a sense that something dangerous could come through.

Answer (score 2):

It was [*Foreign Exchange*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0401934/) (2004) I guess, I was looking for it too.

> Hannah O'Flaherty is a normal sixteen year old girl staying at O'Keffee's Boarding School run by Miss Murphy in Galway, Ireland. One day, when Hannah was going down into the basement, she slipped and opened a secret portal to Perth, Australia. On the other side of the portal lives Brett Miller, a typical Aussie teenager who lives with his recently re-married mother Jackie. Brett gets a job in Hannah's boarding school as a cleaner. Brett's new happy family life, including his new step-dad Craig and step-brother Wayne, cause problems for him and Hannah.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your posts if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)